# How to make udaSQL behave like BTEQ

Tags: jdbc, ant, teradata

I have some BTEQ files that I want to migrate to udaSQL via

```
 <udaSQL src="batch.sql" />
```

Problem is, BTEQ separates the statements so it sends them to teradata one by one, including each one of them in an implicit transaction. Which is fine, because many of them are DDLs (CREATE AS SELECT, DROP, COLLECT STATISTICS...) and they are required to be executed in a single transaction.
BUT udaSQL collects the hole file and tries to send it in a single command with an implicit transaction, which fails when it finds DDLs. 
udaSQL can be tuned in this regard at the JDBC connection string level with one option : transaction mode (TMODE=ANSI/TERA). Setting ANSI mode didn't help, and I don't think it's a good option if it worked, the side effects of changing that for working scripts are scary.
Is there any workaround? Modifying the scripts would be fine, something like putting an "ET" or an extra semicolon after DDL's (which didn't work) What I DO want is the whole batch in separate single file. I don't want a horror like

```
<udaSQL>
DROP TABLE blah;
</udaSQL>
<udaSQL>
CREATE hugeselect AS SELECT blah for 50 lines
</udaSQL>
<udaSQL>
DROP TABLE foo;
</udaSQL>
<udaSQL>
DROP TABLE blah;
</udaSQL>
```

for 500 lines of my ANT file.

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour only applies to embbeded sql in the udasql tag (which I hadn't realize). Using src is fine, udasql executes the ; delimited queries one by one.